# Compound ChildField source

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I would like to have a `<ChildField/>` with a `source` that would be computed on the fly instead of coming from a single attribute.

```
<ReferenceManyField references="users" target="...">
    <SingleFieldList>
        <ChipField source={["first_name", "last_name"]}/>
    </SingleFieldList>
</ReferenceManyField/>
```

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Fields.html#referencemanyfield

Instead of a single source, I would like to take many keys and produce one element, just like it done for the `PostTitle` in [the tutorial](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Tutorial.html#creation-and-editing). How can I adapt the `<ChipField/>` to accomodate creating a complex output combining multiple sources?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: @gravityplanx I've added a proper question... my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still very vague, but it seems like maybe you're simply overlooking a core aspect of react.

Components can take in *any* arguments, and props can be defined completely dynamically.  You are not limited to a `source` attribute.

You could rewrite your above code as:

```
<ChipField firstLabel="firstname" secondLabel="lastName"/>
```

Or whatever other naming convention you desire.  And then within `ChipField` you would just reference those values as `this.props.firstLabel` and `this.props.secondLabel`.

Comment: I assume you need to have access to ChipField source code for that or at least extend it?